# SXA Variant Switcher

Tags: sxa

we have a requirement to allow end user to Switch between two view ( list view and grid view ) for a media library images , we setup the render variants for these views but my question is how to provide the end user to the choice to change the render variant of a competent at runtime , is this something that we can control by query string for example ?

Comment: Why not just write both views into a single variant and write some javascript to switch. Would be much easier than a full page reload to load in a new rendering variant output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will provide several options. I will sort them by effort. You might notice that as effort is higher your flexibility is also better when it comes to customization/configuration.

## OOTB solution

You haven't specified which SXA rendering you've used to render media items.

There is only one OOTB rendering that can make something like this happen (`Search Results` + `Results Variant Selector`).

[image]

Results are loaded async (not server side) so they won't be visible immediately after page load.

#### Pros

- you don't have to code anything
- page reload is not needed (but there are callbacks to server for results with different HTML)
- you've got UI exposed to users already in place (these icons to switch variant)

#### Cons

- you have to setup search

## Personalization

You can have two copies of the same rendering in a placeholder and show/hide them depending on a condition (in your case it's a query string parameter but it can be any of personalization rules conditions).

[image]

**rendering - version 1 settings**

[image]

**rendering - version 2 settings**

[image]

#### Cons

- I don't know your version setup but you will have to enable personalization if for any reason you've disabled it
- you must implement additional control/switch to change query string of a current page to let visitors see a different variant

## Both variants defined in a single variant

Already proposed by **@Richard Seal**.

You could configure two variants inside a single variant and then control it in your preferred way.

[image]

You've got two options here:

- JS based - you need additional control/switch to show/hide variant section 1 or 2 (you can use CSS class for that)
- Rules based - there is a `Rule` field on variant fields (not sure what is your version, it wasn't there since beginning) that you can use to show/hide different sections (server side)

[image]

#### Pros

- single rendering on a page
- easy to re-configure later
- [Rules based] - personalization is not needed. Rules engine works without it

#### Cons

- you must implement additional control/switch to change query string of a current page to let visitors see a different variant

## Rebel

If you don't want to use any of solutions listed above because they are not flexible enough you can overwrite your rendering's repository and provide your own implementation of `VariantItem` property.

Property was defined in
`Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Repositories.AbstractVariantsRepository`

It's time consuming as you have to do everything your way. The only advantage is that you can define different variants and switch them inside this overwritten property.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alan Płócieniak for the proposed solutions its really do the job